# Convert a 3d drillhole trace to cartesian coordinates and plot it with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I would like to be able to plot two lines using direction and distance.  It is a Drillhole trace, so I have the data in this format right now,

[image]

The depth is actually distance down the hole, not vertical depth.  Azimuth is from magnetic north.  Dip is based on 0 being horizontal.  I want to plot two lines from the same point (0,0,0 is fine) and see how they differ, based on this kind of info.

I have no experience with Matplotlib but am comfortable with Python and would like to get to know this plotting tool.  I have found [this page](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/lines3d_demo.html) and it helped to understand the framework, but I still can't figure out how to plot lines with 3d vectors. Can someone give me some pointers on how to do this or where to find the directions I need?  Thank you

Comment: The first step, and probably the biggest challenge, is to find a way to convert this data into cartesian coordinates. Then, you just need to [plot them](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html)

Comment: I was hoping that this was a fairly common task and a module would be available inside matplotlib.  I've done this in 2d with shapely, I'll look to see if someone's made a 3d equivalent.

Comment: matplotlib supports polar coordinates, but if I'm reading your explanation correctly, you need to shift your "center" for each point, and perform corrections in the angles, depending on how you want the final result oriented

Comment: That's right.  Start at 0,0,0.  Find the next coordinate that 255.6° on the horizontal plane, 79.5° down from the horizontal plane, and 14 M from 0,0,0.  Then from that found coordinate, find the next, etc...

Comment: Check out [this Wolfram article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html) on spherical coordinates and conversion to Cartesian. Could be useful...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A script converting your coordinates to cartesian and plotting it with matplotlib with the comments included:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# import for 3d plot
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
# initializing 3d plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
# several data points 
r = np.array([0, 14, 64, 114])
# get lengths of the separate segments 
r[1:] = r[1:] - r[:-1]
phi = np.array([255.6, 255.6, 261.7, 267.4])
theta = np.array([-79.5, -79.5, -79.4, -78.8])
# convert to radians
phi = phi * 2 * np.pi / 360.
# in spherical coordinates theta is measured from zenith down; you are measuring it from horizontal plane up 
theta = (90. - theta) * 2 * np.pi / 360.
# get x, y, z from known formulae
x = r*np.cos(phi)*np.sin(theta)
y = r*np.sin(phi)*np.sin(theta)
z = r*np.cos(theta)
# np.cumsum is employed to gradually sum resultant vectors 
ax.plot(np.cumsum(x),np.cumsum(y),np.cumsum(z))
```

Comment: That is super!  Thank you.  There is a lot in there.  That's slick to do the transformations to all the points and then just add them up to get each coordinate.  I'm still wrapping my head around the phi and theta conversions out of polar coordinates.  I don't understand how the r[1:] = r[1:] - r[:-1] works though.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: @cndnflyr `r[1:] = r[1:] - r[:-1]` is the same as saying [r[n+1] - r[n] for n in range(1,len(r))] -- if that even helps. In words: start at the second element of `r` and redefine each subsequent element as the different between it and the *original* previous element.

Comment: @Paul Thank you, that does help.  It's using two lists taken out of the original and using the list starting at r[0] to subtract from the list starting at r[1].  Because they are the same length, this works.  That's great.

Comment: as a strange side point`r[1:] - r[:-1]` is faster than `np.diff(r)`.

Comment: @tcaswell: This might be because of function call overhead - `np.diff` is recursive.

Answer (score 2):

For a drillhole with 500 m you may use minimum curvature method, otherwise the position error will be really large. I implemented this in a python module for geostatistics (PyGSLIB). An example showing a complete desurvey process for a real drillhole database, including positions at assay/lithology intervals is shown at:

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/opengeostat/pygslib/blob/master/pygslib/Ipython_templates/demo_1.ipynb

This also shows how to export drillholes in VTK format to lad it in paraview.

[Results shown in Paraview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wvyw0.png)

The code in Cython to desurvey one interval is as follows:

```
cpdef dsmincurb( float len12,
                 float azm1,
                 float dip1,
                 float azm2,
                 float dip2):

    """    
    dsmincurb(len12, azm1, dip1, azm2, dip2)

    Desurvey one interval with minimum curvature 

    Given a line with length ``len12`` and endpoints p1,p2 with 
    direction angles ``azm1, dip1, azm2, dip2``, this function returns 
    the differences in coordinate ``dz,dn,de`` of p2, assuming
    p1 with coordinates (0,0,0)

    Parameters
    ----------
    len12, azm1, dip1, azm2, dip2: float
        len12 is the length between a point 1 and a point 2.
        azm1, dip1, azm2, dip2 are direction angles azimuth, with 0 or 
        360 pointing north and dip angles measured from horizontal 
        surface positive downward. All these angles are in degrees.


    Returns
    -------
    out : tuple of floats, ``(dz,dn,de)``
        Differences in elevation, north coordinate (or y) and 
        east coordinate (or x) in an Euclidean coordinate system. 

    See Also
    --------
    ang2cart, 

    Notes
    -----
    The equations were derived from the paper: 
        http://www.cgg.com/data//1/rec_docs/2269_MinimumCurvatureWellPaths.pdf

    The minimum curvature is a weighted mean based on the
    dog-leg (dl) value and a Ratio Factor (rf = 2*tan(dl/2)/dl )
    if dl is zero we assign rf = 1, which is equivalent to  balanced 
    tangential desurvey method. The dog-leg is zero if the direction 
    angles at the endpoints of the desurvey intervals are equal.  

    Example
    --------

    >>> dsmincurb(len12=10, azm1=45, dip1=75, azm2=90, dip2=20)
    (7.207193374633789, 1.0084573030471802, 6.186459064483643)

    """

    # output
    cdef:
        float dz
        float dn
        float de 


    # internal 
    cdef:
        float i1
        float a1
        float i2
        float a2
        float DEG2RAD
        float rf
        float dl

    DEG2RAD=3.141592654/180.0

    i1 = (90 - dip1) * DEG2RAD
    a1 = azm1 * DEG2RAD

    i2 = (90 - dip2) * DEG2RAD
    a2 = azm2 * DEG2RAD

    # calculate the dog-leg (dl) and the Ratio Factor (rf)
    dl = acos(cos(i2-i1)-sin(i1)*sin(i2)*(1-cos(a2-a1))) 

    if dl!=0.: 
        rf = 2*tan(dl/2)/dl  # minimum curvature
    else:
        rf=1                 # balanced tangential



    dz = 0.5*len12*(cos(i1)+cos(i2))*rf
    dn = 0.5*len12*(sin(i1)*cos(a1)+sin(i2)*cos(a2))*rf
    de = 0.5*len12*(sin(i1)*sin(a1)+sin(i2)*sin(a2))*rf

    return dz,dn,de
```

Comment: The entire python module can be installed with conda, with a single line of code `conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/opengeostat pygslib`. It uses GPL/MIT license and is develop by Opengeostat Consulting

Comment: This is interesting. Is it possible for you to rehost the ipynb somewhere?

Comment: Sure, the IPython and testing data is here: https://opengeostat.github.io/pygslib/Tutorial.html. You may want to do some updates if you use the development version of pygslib to run this code.